# Select elements which has data-* with specific pattern using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have many input elements in my page which are like ( simplification) :

```
<input  class='tb' data-mx-a1="dummyA"  
                   data-mx-b20="dummyB" 
                   data-mx-c99="dummyC" />
```

I need to select all elements that has dataattributes which *starts* with `data-mx-*`

Apparently using this : won't help :

[image]

eg :

`$(".tb").filter(function (){return $(this).is('[name^="value"]');}).data();` // we can't use it here

**Question**

How can I do it in the  most effective way ?

*nb It should be cross browser solution (ie8+) , performance is important.*